# MLP mixer - Saving the training model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train the MLP mixer on a custom dataset based on [this repository](https://github.com/rishikksh20/MLP-Mixer-pytorch).

The code I have so far is shown below. How can I save the training model to further use it on test images?

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch import nn
from einops.layers.torch import Rearrange
import glob
import cv2
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class customDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.imags_path = '/path_to_dataset/'
        file_list = glob.glob(self.imags_path + '*')
        self.data = []
        for class_path in file_list:
            class_name = class_path.split('/')[-1]
            for img_path in glob.glob(class_path + '/*.jpg'):
                self.data.append([img_path,class_name])
        self.class_map = {'dogs':0, 'cats':1}
        self.img_dim = (416,416)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        img_path,class_name = self.data[idx]
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        img = cv2.resize(img,self.img_dim)
        class_id = self.class_map[class_name]
        img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(img)
        img_tensor = img_tensor.permute(2, 0, 1)
        class_id = torch.tensor([class_id])
        return img_tensor, class_id

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, hidden_dim, dropout = 0.):
        super().__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Dropout(dropout),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, dim),
            nn.Dropout(dropout)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)

class MixerBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dim, num_patch, token_dim, channel_dim, dropout = 0.):
        super().__init__()

        self.token_mix = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LayerNorm(dim),
            Rearrange('b n d -> b d n'),
            FeedForward(num_patch, token_dim, dropout),
            Rearrange('b d n -> b n d')
        )

        self.channel_mix = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LayerNorm(dim),
            FeedForward(dim, channel_dim, dropout),
        )

    def forward(self, x):

        x = x + self.token_mix(x)

        x = x + self.channel_mix(x)

        return x


class MLPMixer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, dim, num_classes, patch_size, image_size, depth, token_dim, channel_dim):
        super().__init__()

        assert image_size % patch_size == 0, 'Image dimensions must be divisible by the patch size.'
        self.num_patch =  (image_size // patch_size) ** 2
        self.to_patch_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, dim, patch_size, patch_size),
            Rearrange('b c h w -> b (h w) c'),
        )

        self.mixer_blocks = nn.ModuleList([])

        for _ in range(depth):
            self.mixer_blocks.append(MixerBlock(dim, self.num_patch, token_dim, channel_dim))

        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(dim)

        self.mlp_head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, num_classes)
        )

    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.to_patch_embedding(x)

        for mixer_block in self.mixer_blocks:
            x = mixer_block(x)

        x = self.layer_norm(x)

        x = x.mean(dim=1)

        return self.mlp_head(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    dataset = customDataset()
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)

    mixer_model = MLPMixer(in_channels=3, 
        image_size=416, 
        patch_size=16, 
        num_classes=2,
        dim=512, 
        depth=8, 
        token_dim=256, 
        channel_dim=2048)

    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader,0):
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        inputs, labels = inputs.float(), labels.float()
        outputs = mixer_model(inputs)
```

Thanks.

Comment: add this line after traning your model:  `torch.save(mixer_model.state_dict(), 'model.pt')`

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply. So, should I insert the statement after the last for-loop.

Comment: Yes, after the last for-loop.